# How can I handle multiple instances of the same table having different data types connecting to same EF model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is meant to function both in a development and production environment. I used an existing DB and Table in our development environment (which is also present in production) to generate the EF models and wrote all code based on it.

Now, we're moving the application into production, and the table there has a different 'bool' data type than the development table. The dev table uses bit(1) to represent a boolean value, while the prod table uses smallint. Unfortunately, simply changing the data type in production is not an option, as other essential applications rely on it.

As this application continues to expand, it will encounter other versions of this table which could use other data types.

Is it possible to conditionally convert data to boolean, regardless of the data type in the table?

For example, there is an IsAuthorized column. It has the same column name regardless of the environment, but could have different data types. Can I add logic to determine the data type of the IsAuthorized column and then convert it to System.Boolean (for EF model) based on the column's type?

Comment: You have to separate your development environment from the production. This can be done using specific build, using git branches and so on ... so that when you're on the 'dev' branch you work with the most up to date EF model, and when you're on the production branch, you work with the current deployed EF model. But when you deliver some updates, you need to provide schema updates accordingly to production table.
Else for an immediate resolution, why not integrate the change in your development table so that it match exactly the production table?

Comment: Don't make a noose for your own neck; change dev to match prod and tweak the app..

Comment: [Preprocessor directives?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) But like the others have said... probably better off changing one of the environments to match the other (Dev to match Production it seems is easiest).

Comment: Thanks everyone! We ended up getting lucky and were able to standardize both dev and prod to use the same data type. I'll keep your advice in mind next time I run into something similar